# Impact of changing server machines names with SQL Server 2016 Standard in mirror state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, configuration, mirroring, connectivity

It's an enterprise network domain.

Two existing Windows server 2016 machines, one each for SQL Server 2016 Standard edition and other is also SQL Server 2016 Standard edition in a `passive mirror configuration.`

For some reason we need to change both server machine names from say A to B and A1 to B1.

Will this have any impact on SQL Server and its passive mirror access?

What precautions I need to take?

I can understand the connection string with change but I am looking for impact of this change on mirroring configuration particularly

Comment: Are you *truly* renaming the servers or installing new servers with a different name and migrating databases after?  If you're renaming is there any reason why you wouldn't be able to use a [DNS Alias/CNAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/create-an-alias-cname-record-in-dns-for-web1) instead?

Comment: I have not used mirroring since a long time ago, but I think what I would do in this case, stop / remove the mirroring, change the server names, renable the mirroring. Since the LSN should not change (a lot) after the server name changes, you should be able to reconfigure mirroring and allow the mirror to recover itself from the current log in the primary  DB. 

Also don't forget to drop old servername from Sql server (sp_dropserver 'myoldserver' ) and add the new one (sp_addserver 'myserver', local).